# Prove existence of the limit

Tags: limits

Let $f(x)$($>0 \forall x \in \mathbb {R}$) be a function which satisfies the following properties,

1. $f(x)=k$ for some $k>0$ and for infinitely many values of $x$.
2. If $f(x_2)=f(x_1)=k$, with $x_2>x_1$ then $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing for all $x_1<x<x_2$.
3. The difference $(x_2-x_1)$ has no upper bound. $x_2$, $x_1$ denoting the same meaning as in 2.

Then is it true that the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x)$ exists?

I think that some more information about the function $f(x)$ is needed to solve the problem. I don't have any idea as to how to begin with. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming (2) and (1) don't intentionally exclude every possible function, yes and no.

What the caveat is about:  Take $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = f(x_3) = k$.  Strictly decreasing between $x_1$ and $x_3$ contradicts $f(x_2) = k$.

Yes instance:  $f(x) = 2-\frac{1-\text{sawtooth}(x)}{|x|+1} , k = 2, \{x_i\}_i =  \mathbb{Z}$.  Limit is 2 because $1 - \text{sawtooth}(x)$ is bounded below by $0$ and above by $1$.

No instance: $f(x) = 1+\text{sawtooth}(x), k = 2, \{x_i\}_i =  \mathbb{Z}$.  Endlessly cycles from $2$ down to $1$, so the limit does not exist.

See [sawtooth wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), although the decreasing requirement above means we should use the sawtooth leaning the other way: $\lfloor t \rfloor -t$.